# Preventing the adding of a class whilst preventing clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to disable the click and the addition of a class to navbar items in JQM. The click behavior is easy to prevent but I am having a brain fart trying to figure out how to prevent the ui-btn-active class from being applied to the clicked element. I only need the click behavior prevented when current === "Enter New" or current === "Enter Stats"

Preventing the click is easy, but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the class being added even though the click and navigation is prevented.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "[data-role='page']", function () {
    var current = $(this).jqmData('title');
    $("[data-role='header'] h1").text(current);
    $("[data-role='navbar'] a.ui-btn-active").removeClass("ui-btn-active");

    // Add active class to current nav button

    $("[data-role='navbar'] a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-id') === current || $(this).attr('data-alt') === current) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
        }
    });

    if (current === "Enter New" || current === "Enter Stats") {
        $("[data-role='navbar'] a").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it other way:

```
 $("[data-role='navbar'] a").click(function () {
    if (current === "Enter New" || current === "Enter Stats") {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `if()` condition inside click handler.

```
 $("[data-role='navbar'] a").click(function (event) {
     if (current === "Enter New" || current === "Enter Stats") {
         event.preventDefault();
     }

 });
```

Comment: this is not a click handler its a loop `.each()`.

Comment: this is what I did. It prevents the click from following the link however it doesn't prevent the click on another nav bar item from applying the ui-btn-active class. So I stay on the same page but the button for another page is highlighted on the navbar.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of your problem